# How can I train my dogs to let the water drip from their mouths over a certain area after getting a drink?

Tags: dogs, training

Kind of an odd question, but when my dogs go to get a drink, after they finish, water drips from their mouths [quite a lot of it].  Since my apartment is nearly all carpet, the water drops get absorbed which cannot be good for the carpet.  Also, you'll step in wet spots and have to change your socks after!

I have special mats that their bowls sit on to get any splashes of water they make when they get their drink. Ideally, I would like them to allow the water to drip onto these mats, or back into the bowl.

How can I train them to keep their mouths over this area after getting a drink?